# fail to run the scripts - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an html aspx, and I believe your scripts are not loading. I believe this because every time I comment on one of the scripts, it's one less error on the console.

images/prints:

[initially with 11 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sQ44.png)

[10 errors after commenting one of the scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upa4C.png)

And the funniest thing is that the path of the files is right, as it is also set for css.

Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Login.aspx.cs" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/docs.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/select2.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/bootstrap-switch.min.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/css/main.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" />
        
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery3.5.1.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js")%>"></script>

    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/locales/bootstrap-datepicker.pt-BR.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap-switch.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/jquery.mask.js")%>"></script>
    <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/js/main.js")%>"></script>
    
    <script>
        //Remover focus dos campos na tela
        function removeFocus(campo) {
            $("#" + campo.id).blur();
        }
    </script>
    
</head>
```

if I use '*<link href="*' it finds, but I find it doesn't work correctly. Can anyone help me?

**Response for VDWWD:**

[image: Response for VDWWD]

Comment: Can you show the generated html in the head? I copied the snippet to a page and did not get the error you mentioned...

Comment: I put one more image,  Response for VDWWD. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Probably reason is that your **.js files returns an error page** that **starts with** `<html>` and can not compile it to javascript - and that's why you have

> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'**

**Right click on browser page**, view source page, then locate the javascript files **and left click on them to open it on a new tab** to see what is return.

So you actually not load the  .js file, but an error page.

---

Other possible reason can be the file encoding - make sure that is utf-8 and you have declare that on web.config as:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Comment: javascript files don't even load, they don't show up in the browser. :(